# What's the best way to monitor a server reboot?

Tags: powershell, reboot

I have a powershell script that restarts a server. I also wanted this script to monitor when the server goes down and when it comes back up.
Right now I'm using the command:

```
   Test-Connection
```

Is this the right way to do it? Is there a better way to do this? Maybe through Event Viewer?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Normally you can use a `while` loop with `Test-Connection` combined with `Start-Sleep`, I don't see nothing wrong with that. If ICMP is filtered you could use `Test-NetConnection` to a port you know is Listening on the remote host.

Comment: How are you restarting the computer? `Restart-Computer` has a built in Wait switch for waiting you can specify for a particular service etc. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Restart-Computer to restart the server. I this using the while option is a good approach. I was doing it already, I just wasn't sure if there was a more reliable way (like event viewer) to monitor the restart process. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use a tool like Solarwinds or Kaseya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a common scaffolding I use in situations like this:

```
$maxTries = 15
while (-not(test-connection offLinePC -Count 1 -quiet)){
    "trying again..."
    $i++
    if ($i -eq $maxTries){break;}
}
```

If you don't need to have a maximum number of tries, you could simplify it like this...

```
while (-not(test-connection offLine -Count 1 -quiet)){
    "Waiting for `offLine ` to reboot...trying again..."
}
else{
    "offLine is back online!"
}
```

### Simple Improvement

I actually really dislike the syntax of `Test-Connection`, so I bake a small function into my scripts like this:

```
function WaitForReboot{param($HostName)
    test-connection $HostName -Count 1 -quiet
}

while (WaitForReboot OffLinePc){
    "trying again..."
}
```